# $f$ and $g$ are bijections when $f \circ g \circ f$ is a bijection.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to X$ be such functions that $f \circ g \circ f$ is a bijection. Show that both $f$ and $g$ are bijections.

I can show that $f$ is a bijection easily enough, but don't really know how to show for $g$.

Comment: $g=f^{-1} \circ (f \circ g \circ f) \circ f^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that this question does not remain unanswered, here is the complete solution.

Let $h$ be the inverse of $f \circ g \circ f$.

- The equality $1 = (f \circ g \circ f) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ f \circ h)$ shows that $f$ is right-invertible, and $1 = h \circ (f \circ g \circ f) = (h \circ f \circ g) \circ f$ shows that $f$ is left-invertible. Hence, $f$ is invertible (equivalently, $f$ is a bijection).
- Since $f$ is invertible, $f^{-1} \circ (f \circ g \circ f) \circ f^{-1} = g$.
  This means $g$ is a composition of bijections, so that $g$ is a bijection.